# Synchronize passed value with each resource in module : Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I have **main.tf** file where I have **"eip"** module, and i am passing some instance id's to eip module.

I have **3 eip resources** declared in module, each of them expecting instance id from **main.tf**.

Problem is how each passed value(instance id) from main.tf will go to right resource in module, as I cant change **"eip resources"** name in module as these "eip" are already created, I just collected all 3 "eip" from 3 different files and placed in one file just for optimization purpose.

so do I need some understanding here, or its not possible the way I am assuming it.

Please have a look at screenshot for better understanding issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your EIP module, you should have **only one** resource.

**eip/eip.tf**

```
resource "aws_eip" "eip" {
  instance = var.instance
  vpc      = true
}

output "public_ip" {
  value = aws_eip.eip.public_ip
}
```

Then in the parent module you can access the id using module indices

**main.tf**

```
locals {
  public_ip_first_eip = module.module-generic-eip[0].public_ip
```

Since you are iterating in the parent module, the module will be instantiated three times, and you will get three EIPs - one EIP for each instance.

Comment: Hi @marcin, then what about outputs, i mean if i need three outputs which will be used in reference purpose for other modules, i mean these eip outputs. so how to incorporate that?

because right now i have outputs like this 
`output "ec2-one-static-ip" {
  value = aws_eip.one-ec2.public_ip
}
` 
or should i use like this `module.module-generic-eip[0].public_ip`
And same goes for all others.  ???

Comment: and what about mv commands, i mean i am changing modules here.

so how should terraform mv will be performed. so it can identify this as old resource instead of new.

Comment: @DanishSattar Yes, you have to output the values that you want to access in the parent. I updated the answer. The easiest way is to remove existing EIPs, and redeploy with the new modules.

Comment: Thanks @marcin, things cleared now marking answer as useful :) stay blessed